# How to check if two <tr> elements are equal when ignoring some inner <td> elments?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I am just wondering if is it possible in JavaScript or jQuery to check if two DOM elements are equal when ignoring inner elements.

For example, how to compare two `<tr>`'s and ignore particular `<td>`'s? Is it possible?

Here is a particular case: (ignore td with text1 and text2 values and compare only the date values. Important notice: td elements are without id attributes).

```
<tr id="row1" class="row">
    <td>2010-09-01</td>
    <td>text1</td>
</tr>
<tr id="row2" class="row">
    <td>2010-09-01</td>
    <td>text2</td>
</tr>
```

**EDIT**: snippet added

Comment: Equal in terms of which property?

Comment: Could you show a HTML sample, giving the `td` you want to include/exclude.

Comment: I have added an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    if ($('#row1 tr td:eq(0)').html() == $('#row2 tr td:eq(0)').html())
    {
        alert("same")
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would have thought that the only content within a tr should be td elements, so why not just compare the td's you're interested in and ignore the one you aren't?

Answer (score 0):

Updated:
If you are sure of the td position in tr, you can compare:

```
    if($("#row1 > td").eq(0).text() == $("#row2 > td").eq(1).text())
{
}
```